# entityFramework CreateSourceQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Im using SelfTrackingChanges and on relationship end "MANY" I havent got CreateSourceQuery() method :/

Is there any way I can achieve that still using SelfTrackingChanges ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Only `EntityCollection<TEntity>` and `EntityReference<TEntity>` classes override the [*IRelatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.irelatedend.createsourcequery.aspx) as they implement `IRelatedEnd` interface and they both found on the EntityObjects which means you don't have it on your STEs and POCOs. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are using shared model client app and web app so that we use SelfTrackingChanges on our entities. It is great for web applications and web services but on the windows client it is dissapopinting. When I open my application I need to do a lot of include just like: http://itmeze.com/2009/11/a-hint-for-entity-framework-multi-join-performance-problem/ but I cant use that soultion cause I cant do CreateSourceQuery